# Cannot resolve symbol when referencing .winmd file

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winmd

everyone!
I am a **windows phone 8.1 developper** focus on **Library** developping.
Recently I encouter some strange question.
*Details:*

I have developped **a windows runtime component** named "Com.AMap.Api.Maps"
[image]

In my developping **project**,it works fine.
But,when I new **a wp8.1 app project**,and reference the **output file ".winmd"**
Input a type in the windows runtime component,like this below:
[image]
under normal circumstances，it should work(and **it do work on my college's computer!**)
but in my computer,problem appears
[image]
shows:**cannot resolve symbol "Com"**
but it is different from the misspelled type,because you can go to its definition
[image]

- I have tried reinstalled my Visual studio but the problem remains
- vs 2013 u2

Can you help me?Any advice would be appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

**Uninstall Resharper** and problem disappears

**Discussion here**
[Cannot resolve symbol when referencing .winmd file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/69d85b99-7867-4e7b-95d4-567760da0684/cannot-resolve-symbol-when-referencing-winmd-file?forum=wpdevelop)